# Unable to share image on twitter using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I want to share "image" on twitter with php,In other words i have image and i want
whenever any user click on "share" button then image should post of his "Twitter wall",
I tried with two different code/method but in both cases...image is posting on my wall (i used credentials(token,secret)with my account), so i want image should post on users(who want to share) instead of my "Twitter wall",How can i do this ?
Here is my First code/method which i tried

```
require_once('src/codebird.php');
$image="index.jpg";
$message="Lorem Ipsum dummy text";

// note: consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, and accessTokenSecret all come from your twitter app at https://apps.twitter.com/
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

$reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
    'media' => $image
));

$mediaID = $reply->media_id_string;
$params = array(
    'status' => $message,
    'media_ids' => $mediaID
);
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
```

And i tried with another code/method also, Here is my code

```
require("config.php");
require("vendor/autoload.php");

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$img="index.jpg";
if(isset($_POST['shares'])) {
  
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$media1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => $img]);
$parameters = [
    'status' => 'Lorem Ipsum dummy text!',
    'media_ids' => implode(',', [$media1->media_id_string])
];
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

$id=$result->id;
if($id || $id!=="")
{
    echo "Image uploaded Successfully on twitter";
}
else
{   
    echo "Error! Something went wrong";
}

}

?>
<html>
<form action="index.php" method="POST" name="myform">
<input type="hidden" name="shares" value="shares">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="share">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to have the user authenticate to your app so that you can get their access token and secret to do the post. Check the docs for TwitterOAuth PHP library section on Authorization Flow for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library to post images https://github.com/dg/twitter-php ( https://phpfashion.com/twitter-for-php ):

`composer.json`

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:peterjaap/twitter-php.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "dg/twitter-php": "dev-patch-1"
    }
}
```

`test.php`

```php
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use DG\Twitter\Twitter;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', '...your-code-here');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '...your-code-here');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', '...your-code-here');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', '...your-code-here');

$twitter = new Twitter(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

// optional image/s
$image = "./tempfile.jpg";
file_put_contents($image, fopen("https://live.staticflickr.com/5095/5446290949_73ed733c0d_c.jpg", 'r'));

try {
    $tweet = $twitter->send('this is my cool tweet', array($image)); // you can add $imagePath or array of image paths as second argument
    unlink($image);
} catch (DG\Twitter\TwitterException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

don't forget to add write permission to your twitter app ( https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard )

[image: twitter write permission]

Comment: Please don't repeat the same answer on multiple questions. If multiple questions can be answered by the same answer, consider marking them as duplicates. If they aren't duplicates, then your answer should, at minimum, be customized to the specifics of the question.